# Why parameterless constructor being invoked after constructor with parameters is invoked, deleting my changes in C# MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using WPF to create a desktop application and MVVM without any framework as architecture. In the XAML, I have a text box binded with a PersonViewModel Name variable:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

And the code behind code of this view looks like this:

```
 public partial class PersonView : UserControl
    {
        public PersonView()
        {
            PersonViewModel vm = new PersonViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
```

And then the ViewModel that is binded to the PersonView:

```
public class PersonViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    public string _Name;
    public string Name{
        get => _Name;
        set{ _Name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public PersonViewModel(){}

    public PersonViewModel(Person person){
        Name = person.Name;
    }
}
```

In MainWindowViewModel I create a new instance of PersonViewModel, this to change the `ContentControl` Content property of MainWindow where PersonView is, so then when a button is clicked, I change the view to PersonView.
I create the new instance of PersonViewModel like this:

```
Person person = bl.SearchPersonByName("Alex");
changeView(new PersonViewModel(person));
```

In this view model `Name` is a variable bindend to a `TextBox` control. What I want to do is, if PersonViewModel is created with a `Person` in the constructor, to set that `TextBox` `Text` property to the name of the Person passed setting the `Name` variable the same as the `Person` object, if not, the value of `Name`will be null and the user can write his name.
Now, when I create the PersonViewModel with a Person object in the constructor, first executes the constructor with parameters, setting the `Name` variable the same as the Person object passed, but after that, it calls the parameterless constructor and sets the `Name` variable as null. Why is this happening and how can I avoid this?

Comment: Please show the code and XAML parts where you create a PersonViewModel instance, and where you use it.

Comment: How did you bind the property? And how exactly did you observe this behaviour? Did you debug? And did you thereby make sure that the constructors ran for the very same instance? Because I don't think that's possible, the parameterless constructor is not executed if you construct the object with a `Person` argument.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the parameterless ctor and check the stacktrace. Backtrace from there to see where it went wrong.

Comment: please show the code you are using it. for instance if the `Person.Name` of the person passed is null, the value will be null, and you would think that parameterless cunstructor is called

Comment: I updated the question. I had set the Name parameter to "Hi" in the parameterless constructor, and set two breakpoint, one in the constructor with parameters when Name is set to `person.Name` and one in the parameterless where Name is set to Hi. It first runs the parameter constructor, and then the parameterless.

Comment: You're not passing a `Person` to the view model when you create it in `PersonView`.

Comment: So when the parameterless constructor is run, you are sure that `_Name` was indeed the value of `person.Name` and not `null` before set to `Hi`? And the code you posted does not show any call to the constructur with parameter.

Comment: @juharr I create a new instance of PersonViewModel from another ViewModel with the person parameter, I've updtated my question to show the scenario.

Comment: @RenéVogt Yes, I've checked the value of person.Name and is not null, is the correct name of the Person object, after that the parameterless constructor is called and Name is setted to "Hi"

Comment: Now the question would be what does `changeView` do.

Comment: @juharr Is changing the MainWindow ContentControl Content binded value to show a new view, in this case PersonViewModel

Answer (score 0):

As René Vogt suggested in the comments, it was not the same instance of PersonViewModel. The problem was that I was defining a new instance without parameters of PersonViewModel as DataContext in the code behind of PersonView, so when I was calling the `changeView` method with the new instance of PersonViewModel with Person parameter, it was first creating the parameter instance, and then, when it shows the view, as the DataContext was assigned to a new instance of PersonViewModel without parameters, it was overriding the one with the Person parameter.
I had already defined the DataContext of PersonViewModel in the App.xaml file like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mv:PersonViewModel}">
                <local:PersonView/>
            </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So defining the DataContext in the PersonView code behind wasn't necessary.

Comment: Explicitly setting the DataContext of a control in its XAML or code behind is not even "not necessary", but actually a programming error. A control is supposed to inherit its DataContext from its parent element, e.g. a Window or Page.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the info! I'm new to WPF and MVVM and is goot to now this! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't know where exactly you use the DataTemplate with the PersonView. If it is in a Window, you may typically set the DataContext of the Window instance. Same for a Page. Then you may have a ContentControl (or ItemsControl) that uses the DataTemplate to show a single (or multiple) PersonViewModel objects by binding its Content (or ItemsSource) property. In such a typical scenario the DataContext of the element in the DataTemplate is set automatically by WPF. You break this behaviour if you set it explicitly.